# Imagen de un ImageView a int AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android

Buenas amigos como puedo pasar la imagen de un `ImageView` a int en andrid studio para poder guardarla en una BD, cargo la imagen desde una base de datos de esta manera:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper adminPlantas = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "Plantas", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatosPlantas = adminPlantas.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor file_plantas = BaseDeDatosPlantas.rawQuery
                ("SELECT * from especies where nombreComun='" + b.getString("nombre")+"'", null);
        if (file_plantas.moveToFirst()) {
            tvNombreE.setText(b.getString("nombre"));
            tvEspecieE.setText(file_plantas.getString(2));
            tvDescripcionE.setText(file_plantas.getString(4));
            imgFotoE.setImageResource(file_plantas.getInt(5));//Aqui mando la imagen al ImageView 
        }
        BaseDeDatosPlantas.close();
```

en la app se cambia la imagen por otra del dispositivo, ahora como hago lo contrario obtener la imagen del `ImageView` y pasarlo a un int y así poder guardarla en BD de nuevo.

```
public void GuardarE(View view) {
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "Plantas", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();
        
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("update especies set descripcion = '"+tvDescripcionE.getText()+"',foto="+imageResource
                +" where nombreComun='"+tvNombreE.getText()+"';");//Aqui es donde necesito el int de la imagen
        BaseDeDatos.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas obtener la imagen que agregaste dentro del `ImageView` previamente, te aconsejo guardar su valor como etiqueta (tag) de tu `ImageView`:

```
imgFotoE.setImageResource(file_plantas.getInt(5)); 
imgFotoE.setTag(file_plantas.getInt(5));
```

de esta forma podras obtener el id de la imagen almacenada dentro del ImageView y posteriormente puedes guardarlo en una base de datos:

```
 int idImagen = imgFotoE.getTag();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar pero ya lo intente de esa manera pero el ```getTag()``` me retorna un dato Object